# Display inputAccessoryView in childViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a parent view controller that acts as a container for a `UIPageViewController`and another `UIViewController` (called `commentsViewController`). I want to show the `inputAccessoryView` inside the `commentsViewController` however it doesn't seem to be working. I have added the `commentsViewController` to the parent like so:

```
commentsViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CommentsViewController")! as! CommentsViewController
self.addChildViewController(commentsViewController)
self.view.addSubview(commentsViewController.view)
//...I have set some autolayout constraints here
commentsViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Then inside `CommentsViewController`, I have the following:

```
@IBOutlet var customView: UIView!
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
    return customView
}

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and the inputAccessoryView is not displayed... Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that because I was animating the view, `becomeFirstResponder()` automatically returned false. After the animation it works fine.

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly do. it didn't work for me

Comment: agree, i would love to know what you did for this to work.

Comment: I also got it to work due his solution. What worked for me was that I have a containerView childcontroller added to the screen with some kind if UIAnimate for showing its content, and I added the ".becomeFirstResponder()" method in the animation's completion handler and than it worked. Good luck!